# What is the difference between double and single bigger than in linux terminal

Tags: linux, io-redirection

what is the difference between " > " and  ">>" in linux  i know it has to do with redirection but not sure what is exactly the difference

example: 
ls > a.txt
ls >> a.txt

Answer (score 11):

You'll find them on manual, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html.

Actualy, `>` is for stdout redirection to file, which is rewrite entire file. `>>` is for append stdout output to the last line.